# How to see embedded mongo db created document structure?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using Spring boot application with embedded mongodb in it, the application is running perfectly, but I am not able to see the the document structure mongodb has generated for the entities. Can anyone help here !

Comment: **mongotemplate.findById("Id");** will give you json structure of your monogo document.

Comment: no I mean is there any browser url where I can check like, h2 database has /cosole url and hsql has DatabaseManagerSwing UI, where we can see table structure and data

Comment: There is no such built-in tool, as I know. But you always can use third-party solution, e.g. **mongo express** (https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express)

Comment: thank you Anatoly, will try that